# how to construct tuple from transform of vector's iteration

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

Currently I come across a problem to convert my json like class to a tuple. The core problem is to transfrom a vector of variant to tuple of specific types.

```
using v_t = variant<int, double, string>
using raw_t = vector<v_t> ;
template <typename... args>
optional<tuple<args...>> try_get_value(const raw_t& input);
```

And the try_get_value function implementation should like below

```
if input.size() != sizeof...(args) return nullopt
for i in xrange(sizeof...(args)):
    if !input[i].holds_alternative<args[i]> return nullopt
return make_tuple(input[i].get<args[i]>()...)
```

For example, I have `data = vector<v_t>({v_t(1), v_t(2)})`, I want get `tuple<int, int>` from this data, so I call `try_get_value<int, int>(data)`, it should return `make_tuple(1,1)`， but if I call `try_get_value<string,string>(data)`, it should return `nullopt`. These args types are provided manually, may not be the same types in the vector of variants.

I spend nearly half a day trying to construct the function body but failed. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you plan to provide template parameters at runtime actually? That's not possible since templates are instantiated at compile time. What are you trying to achieve finally? Sounds like a XY-problem for me.

Comment: what code do you have for now?

Comment: I don't think it's possible since the current type of the `variant` is determined in run-time while the types of `tuple` members - in compile-time.

Comment: @everyone Just that it's not possible to do this in C++ doesn't mean you have to close the question for "unclear what you're asking". I think it's obvious what is being asked (and we had three comments indicating the same).

Comment: the `args ` are the expected types for the data, but the data is construct from inputs, so the `args` may mismatch with data， so I return `optional`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes you can.

```
template <class... Requested, std::size_t... RequestedIdx>
std::optional<std::tuple<Requested...>> try_get_value(
    raw_t const &input, std::index_sequence<RequestedIdx...>
) {
    // At least one of the variant contains an unexpected type, bail out
    if(!(std::holds_alternative<Requested>(input[RequestedIdx]) && ...))
        return {};

    return std::optional<std::tuple<Requested...>>(
        std::in_place, std::get<Requested>(input[RequestedIdx])...
    );
}

template <class... Requested>
std::optional<std::tuple<Requested...>> try_get_value(raw_t const &input) {
    // Incorrect vector size, bail out
    if(input.size() != sizeof...(Requested))
        return {};

    return try_get_value<Requested...>(input, std::index_sequence_for<Requested...>{});
}
```

[See it live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZQQ14got4G1eDOr2)

Comment: Seems right! Those varaidic template magic!  It's 1AM for me and I would check it in the morning.

Comment: @spiritsaway well, good night then :p